# How can i get the week day in text from input date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
 <div class='col-md-2'>
   <div class='form-group'>
    {!! Form::label('date', 'Select Date')!!}
    {!! Form::input('datetime-local','date',Input::get('date'), ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Laravel controller are down, why it comes with an error?

```
$today=$request->date;

$week_day=$today->format('l');

dd($week_day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Carbon

\Carbon\Carbon::parse($today)->format('l')

Comment: i don't need carbon value

Comment: @ParthajyotiSarma, why you can't user Carbon?

Comment: becouse, i need input date value